# Autocompletado phpstorm para Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ide, autocompletar

Tengo la necesidad de que phpstorm me reconozca métodos de clases que he almacenado previamente en un array. He buscado en diversos foros y no encuentro una solución a esta situación que se vuelve tediosa cuando el número de clases crece considerablemente. Intentaré mostrar un ejemplo gráfico que sea lo más ilustrativo posible.

```
<?php namespace App\Factory;

use App\Bo\PerfilDocumental;

class PerfilDocumentalCollection
{
    private $collection;

   /**
    * @return PerfilDocumentalCollection
    */
   public function getCollection()
   {
       return $this->collection;
   }

   /**
    * @param PerfilDocumental $perfilDocumental
    */
   public function setCollection(PerfilDocumental $perfilDocumental)
   {
      $this->collection[] = $perfilDocumental;
   }


}
```

A partir de esta clase, voy almacenando instancias de la clase PerfilDocumental.
El problema con phpstorm lo tengo cuando intento acceder a los métodos (getters/setters) de esta última en las iteraciones de la colección.

```
        $collection = new PerfilDocumentalCollection();
        foreach ( $rows AS $row )
        {
            $perfil = new PerfilDocumentalFactory();
            $collection->setCollection($perfil->get_instance($row));
        }

        foreach ( $collection->getCollection() AS $key => $obj )
        {
            echo "Creado por: " . $obj->getCreatedBy()->getNom() . " el " . $obj->getCreatedAtWeb()."<br>";
            echo "Actualitzado por: " . $obj->getUpdatedBy()->getNom() . " el " . $obj->getUpdatedAtWeb()."<br>";
        }
```

Es decir, dentro del segundo bloque foreach intento acceder a los métodos getCreatedBy(), etc de la instancia de la clase PerfilDocumental (variable $obj), pero phpstorm no sugiere nada en el paso:

```
        foreach ( $collection->getCollection() AS $key => $obj )
        {
            echo $obj->.......
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Saludos a tod@s,

Finalmente he logrado lo que esperaba y ha sido más fácil de lo que creía (llegué a pensar que no se podía)....

Añadiendo una sola línea de comentario, phpstorm entiende lo que el developer necesita y el autocompletado se activa de inmediato.

/* @var $variable_del_objeto Nombre_clase_del_objeto */
Con esta única línea, se activa el autocompletado en el IDE

```
        /* @var $obj PerfilDocumental */
        foreach ( $collection->getCollection() AS $obj )
        {
            echo "Creado por: " . $obj->getCreatedBy()->getNom() . " el " . $obj->getCreatedAtWeb()."<br>";
            echo "Actualitzado por: " . $obj->getUpdatedBy()->getNom() . " el " . $obj->getUpdatedAtWeb()."<br>";
            echo "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
        }
```

Espero que os llegue a resultar de utilidad.